# Accesing SharedPreferences from different IntentService

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, intentservice

I am having a problem when accessing shredPreferences from inside an IntentService

this is the error i get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.androidbook.btdt.hour6.QuizSettingsActivity$UploaderService: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The nullpointer exception comes when

```
mGameSettings = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This is the code:

```
public static  class UploaderService extends IntentService{

String DEBUG_TAG = UploaderService.class.getSimpleName();

SharedPreferences mGameSettings;



private UpLoadUserData upLoadUserData;

/**
 * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
 *
 * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
 */
public UploaderService(String name) {
    super(name);
    mGameSettings = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public UploaderService(){
    super("");
    mGameSettings = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

This is how I start the IntentService:

```
    Intent uploadService = new Intent(this,UploaderService.class);
    startService(uploadService);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do that line in the startService function and not the constructor.  I know at least for activities at construct time the Context is not fully set up so many calls would fail.  I believe services are the same way.

Comment: Actually, that would be `onCreate()`, after the call to `super.onCreate()`.

Comment: Bleh, you're right.  Maybe I should stop answering questions today, I'm obviously a step slower than usual :)